# How can I create a custom filter type using log4rs?

Tags: logging, rust, yaml, rust-cargo, rust-crates

The only available filter is a level threshold, but say I wanted to filter by a specific `target: $expr` instead. How would I programmatically (or in the yml file) let log4rs know that I need a different kind of filter? Would I need to add a custom feature to accommodate the addition of my new filter type that implements the filter trait?

I have tried implementing my own filter type with all of the associated implementations as per the source code in the [documentation of the threshold filter type](https://docs.rs/log4rs/0.13.0/src/log4rs/filter/threshold.rs.html#1-71). I even have the custom filter name specified in the `- kind:` section of a filter the the `.yml` config file. What more could log4rs need to implement something like this?

In addition, I am receiving the following error when I run `let handle = log4rs::load_config_file("../log4rs.yml", Default::default()).unwrap();`

log4rs: error deserializing filter attached to appender custom_filter_appender: no filter deserializer for kind `custom_filter` registered

Even though I have explicitly defined a deserializer for said custom filter.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few point to respond to with this question:

1. First, with reference to filtering by `target: $expr`, you can get away with merely creating a new logger that shares the same name as the target(s) you'd like to filter by. This is because `log4rs` only sends macros from the `log` crate to loggers with the same target string as the logger name. As such, there is a kind of built in filtering going on here.
2. Second, with regard to needing a custom feature, you don't need one. Everything I will show below did not require a custom feature to run.
3. Thirdly, and most interestingly, is the syntax and form of creating a custom filter. I will detail the necessary modifications below:

First the configuration log4rs.yml file:

```
 appenders:
    custom_filter_appender:
        kind: file
        path: "log/custom_filter.log"
        filters:
        - kind: custom_filter
        interesting_field: interesting_value
        encoder:
          pattern: "{d} {m}{n}"
 root:
   level: error
 loggers:
     filter_logger:
       level: <level you want to filter by>
       appenders:
         - custom_filter_appender
       additive: false
```

What I did above illustrates what would be necessary to configure a custom filter with `log4rs` using a configuration file. Observe that filters are attached to appenders and appenders to loggers. This is the only way to attach things. Next I will detail the trait implementations needed in custom_filter.rs for a custom filter and how they will affect the fields representing the `custom_filter`.

```
// First remember to include the appropriate log4rs or whatever other libraries you want in the custom_filter.rs file
#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct CustomFilterConfig {
    interesting_field: InterestingFieldType,
}
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct CustomFilter {
    interesting_field: InterestingFieldType,
}

impl CustomFilter {
    /// Creates a new `CustomFilter` with the specified interesting field.
    pub fn new(interesting_field: InterestingFieldType,) -> CustomFilter {
        CustomFilter { interesting_field }
    }
}

impl Filter for CustomFilter {
    fn filter(&self, record: &Record) -> Response {
        if <Some comparison about self.interesting_field> {
            Response::Accept
        } else {
            Response::Reject
        }
    }
}

pub struct CustomFilterDeserializer;

impl Deserialize for CustomFilterDeserializer {
    type Trait = dyn Filter;

    type Config = CustomFilterConfig;

    fn deserialize(
        &self,
        config: CustomFilterConfig,
        _: &Deserializers,
    ) -> Result<Box<dyn Filter>, Box<dyn Error + Sync + Send>> {
        Ok(Box::new(CustomFilter::new(config.interesting_field)))
    }
}
```

All of these must be implemented if `log4rs` is to have a prayer of recognizing and running your filter. And remember that only `log` crate macros that have the same target as the name `filter_logger` (in this case) will go to this filter for filtering. Now to finish this off we need to know how to set up the `log4rs` configuration from a file in main.rs with the correct filter added so it can be used.

```
let mut custom_filter_deserializer = log4rs::file::Deserializers::new();
custom_filter_deserializer.insert(
    "custom_filter",
    crate::custom_filter::CustomFilterDeserializer,
);
log4rs::init_file("log4rs.yml", custom_filter_deserializer).unwrap();
```

And that should be everything you need to configure a custom filter yourself using `log4rs`.

Comment: Sadly, not working for me.Could you  give me some help?[MY QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67148186/why-custom-filter-not-working-in-log4rs1-0)