# Why custom filter not working in log4rs(1.0)?

Tags: rust, actix-web

I'm trying to create a custom filter for log using `Log4rs` based on `actix-web` but not working.The code mostly from this similar question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64862936/how-can-i-create-a-custom-filter-type-using-log4rs).

Init logger config:

```rust
    pub fn init_config() {
        let mut custom_filter_deserializer = log4rs::config::Deserializers::new();
        custom_filter_deserializer.insert(
            "request_filter",
            CustomFilterDeserializer
        );
        log4rs::init_file("config/log4rs.yaml", custom_filter_deserializer).unwrap_or_else(|e| {
            panic!("init logger file failed: {:?}", e);
        });
    }
```

Custom filter:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct RequestFilterConfig {
    request_field: String
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct RequestFilter {
    request_field: String
}

impl  RequestFilter {
    /// Creates a new `CustomFilter` with the specified interesting field.
    pub fn new(request_field: String) -> Self {
        Self { request_field }
    }
}


impl Filter for RequestFilter {
    fn filter(&self, record: &Record) -> Response {
        println!("RequestFilter {:?}", record);
        let path = record.module_path().unwrap();
        println!("RequestFilter {} - {}", path, &self.request_field);
        if path.contains(&self.request_field)  {
            Response::Accept
        } else {
            Response::Reject
        }
    }
}

pub struct CustomFilterDeserializer;

impl config::Deserialize for CustomFilterDeserializer {
    type Trait = dyn Filter;
    type Config = RequestFilterConfig;

    fn deserialize(&self, config: RequestFilterConfig, _: &config::Deserializers) ->  anyhow::Result<Box<dyn Filter>> {
        let filter = RequestFilter::new(config.request_field);
        println!("CustomFilterDeserializer {:?}", &filter);
        Ok(Box::new(filter))
    }
}
```

The place I use:

```rust
#[get("/posts")]
async fn posts(pool: web::Data<DbPool>) -> Result<HttpResponse, ApiError> {
    info!("get posts");
    let conn = pool.get().expect("couldn't get db connection from pool");
    let posts_result = web::block(move || db::get_posts(&conn)).await.map_err(|e| {
        eprintln!("{:?}", e);
        HttpResponse::InternalServerError().finish()
    });
    match posts_result {
        Ok(posts) => Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().json(posts)),
        Err(error) => Ok(error),
    }
}
```

The config yaml file:

```yaml
refresh_rate: 30 seconds
appenders:
  stdout:
    kind: console
  requests:
    kind: file
    path: "log/requests.log"
    filters:
      - kind: request_filter
        request_field: api
    encoder:
      pattern: "{d} {l} {t} - {m}{n}"
root:
  level: info
  appenders:
    - stdout
loggers:
  requests_logger:
    level: info
    appenders:
      - requests
    additive: false
```

From the view of console output, It seems like the program even not run into the `RequestFilter::filter` method:

```
CustomFilterDeserializer RequestFilter { request_field: "api" }
logger init success!
env init success!
db pool init success!
ssl pool init success!
2021-04-18T19:41:51.590650400+08:00 INFO actix_server::builder - Starting 12 workers
2021-04-18T19:41:51.592819400+08:00 INFO actix_server::builder - Starting "actix-web-service-0.0.0.0:8080" service on 0.0.0.0:8080
2021-04-18T19:41:51.592876400+08:00 INFO actix_server::builder - Starting "actix-web-service-0.0.0.0:8083" service on 0.0.0.0:8083
2021-04-18T19:42:02.698122400+08:00 INFO actix_angular_web::api - get posts
2021-04-18T19:42:02.705875900+08:00 INFO actix_web::middleware::logger - 127.0.0.1:33200 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0
```

Where is wrong?

Full code can be found here : https://github.com/lazystitan/actix-angular-web

Comment: Hey @Riton Elion, it seems log4rs has updated since my answer that you linked in your question. But other than the return type of the deserializers() fn it ought to work the same as before. I noticed that you showed the stdout output in your question statement but not whether the `log/request.log` file had been created. Could you check for that file and whether your logging info is there because that's where you told log4rs to put it in your yaml file. If that's not the case you might be over-writting the requests_logger somehow. Keep me posted either way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's time to answer this for myself.

The goal is to let emitted records write into different files since they were emitted in diffrent functional part of the program.

There is no need to using custom filter, we can easily filter records by the loggers' name:

A record emitted in `crate_name::module_name(::module_name...)::function_name` is send to the logger with correspond name `crate_name::module_name(::module_name...)::function_name` or it's ancestor `crate_name::module_name(::module_name...)`.

But be ware of the name of crate which contains `-` will automaticly transform to a name only with `_` when program runing.

eg. in my case `actix-angular-web` => `actix_angular_web`.

So, instead of `actix-angular-web::apis::get_posts`, I should use `actix_angular_web::apis::get_posts`.